# Overhead metal door adjustment

Tags: garage-door

My overhead metal door is “wedging” when close to bottom but also is hitting a track mounting bolt when it is forced up from inside.  When I push up from outside, it does not hit the bolt(s).  I believe the door is too close to the side where it is hitting the track mounting bolts.  How do I slide the door over?

Comment: I wonder if the cables for the torsion spring have slipped or moved?  Check the attachment of the cables to the door... carefully.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. [What kind of garage door is this](https://www.bobvila.com/articles/2449-garage-doors-101/)? Could you post a picture of the inside of the door when it's down?